# typo3 tx-news create a custom record type

Tags: typo3, tx-news

i know how to create new **news types** thats stated here https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Tutorials/ExtendNews/AddCustomType/Index.html

But is it possible to extend it so that i can make a complete unique record type?
For example:

[image]

I want something like: "News Tag 2" - so a different type of record with different fields i can save.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by writing your own extension which contains the new type as Exbase model. Then you can attach it to the news record by extending the news domain model

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you maybe know good resources i can look at?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://daniel-siepmann.de/posts/2019/typo3-plugins-as-content-elements.html